# How to implement N-dimensional Venn Diagram in Java? and How to integrate Html/JavaScript code into Java plugin?

Tags: javascript, java, html, venn-diagram

I want to ask that I have Java plugin application. Now, I want to implement n-dimentional Venn Diagram by specifically mentioning the percentage of overlapped and seperate regions. I don't need boolean implementation of Venn diagram.

One of the implementation in Java, I have found from http://www.eulerdiagrams.org/eulerAPE/#GettingStarted. But, it is limited to exactly 3 datasets. I want to compare flexible number of datasets by using venn diagram, in such a way that I will provide following inputs:

1. Number of data sets like 2. Suppose A and B are datasets which will have 3 regions in the venn diagram.
2. Percentage area of each region in Venn diagram
3. Colors of each region
4. Labels of each region

Can any knows how can I implement it? Is there any source code available in Java?

Secondly, I can adopt alternative way as well, which is to use Html/Javascript implementation of n-dimensional Venn Diagram. I have found multiple implementations of n-dimensional Venn Diagram Javascript/Html code like https://github.com/benfred/venn.js etc

But, major challenge becomes to integrate source code Java plugin with Html/Javascript. Can you please let me know is there any way to integrate Javascript/Html Venn diagram implementation in my Java plugin?

Please let me know about some solution.

Comment: Translate the javascript source code to java. Sounds simpler than it actually is thougj.

Comment: Thanks Balint for reply, Can you plz recommend some tool for translating javascript source code into java? 
Secondly, I have html code as well. How can it be integrated into Java Plugin Code? 
Is it possible to open up a panel which is designed through html/javascript, from Java plugin code?

Comment: Well, there are no tools like that (at least I don't think that would produce a usable code). You need to do that by hand. And you should also be able to make everything you have in html with JPanel.

Comment: Utilizing Html code in JPanel sounds me a good solution. Thanks Balint

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: I have never done this activity before. 
Will I face any compatibility issues? or What type of issues do I face while using html, and javascript source code of Venn Diagram in JPanel? 
Please suggest.

Comment: I said that you can't use html in JPanel.

Comment: Please suggest about is there any way to utilize Html and java-script in Java Plugin source code?

Comment: I say it the fourth abd last time: No, I don't think there is, and if by some luck there is, I'm 99% sure it wouldn't produce something useful